# Raincloud plot for time series data across runs

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, time-series

I am struggling to make a rain-cloud graph by following the codes given in **Allen, M., Poggiali, D., Whitaker, K., Marshall, T. R., & Kievit, R. A. (2019)*. Raincloud plots: a multi-platform tool for robust data visualization.* for the graph parallel to Figure 10 in the article mentioned. I am expecting to get rain clouds for every point in time. But I get collective graphs irrespective of the time given on x-axis.
Here is the sample data I am using;

```
set.seed(123)
  ID = rep(c("BAU","IMP","SGR","CR"), each=5000)
  Time = rep (c(1:1000), each = 20)
  data <- data.frame( ID, Time,  profits = runif(20000,0,1))
```

codes are given as follows:

```
source("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/benmarwick/2a1bb0133ff568cbe28d/raw/fb53bd97121f7f9ce947837ef1a4c65a73bffb3f/geom_flat_violin.R")

    data <- data.frame( ID, Time,  profits = runif(20000,0,1))
      AD<- ggplot(data, aes(x = Time, y = profits, fill = ID)) +
        geom_flat_violin(aes(fill = ID),position = position_nudge(x =.1
                                                                                   , y = 0), adjust = 1.5, trim = FALSE, alpha = .5, colour = NA)+
        geom_point(aes(x = as.numeric(ID)-.15, y =profits, colour = ID
        ),position = position_jitter(width = .05), size = 1, shape = 20)+
        geom_boxplot(aes(x =Time,  y = profits, fill = ID),outlier.shape
                     = NA, alpha = .5, width = .1, colour = "black")+ 
        scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Dark2")+
        scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2")+  theme_classic() + theme(legend.position="top") +
        ggtitle("Profits Across Pysical Experiments")
```

and I got the following plot
[image]

I require to see that how these plots look like if plotted for every point in time. Can anybody help?

update: resulted graphs2 from codes followed from comments below
[image]

Comment: Dear Sadaf, always add `ggplot2` tag on your questions for which you have used this package. It is considered the most relevant tag.

Comment: What package are you getting geom_flat_violin from?

Comment: @Jon from here https://orchid00.github.io/tidy_raincloudplot... source("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/benmarwick/2a1bb0133ff568cbe28d/raw/fb53bd97121f7f9ce947837ef1a4c65a73bffb3f/geom_flat_violin.R").

Comment: You have 1000 Time values -- do you want to show 1000 rainclouds?

Comment: may be 40 steps each @JonSpring

Comment: @Sadaf, that you'll have to decide.  40 steps means you want 25 rainclouds?

Comment: @AnilGoyal that is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider adding `group = Time %/% 10` or similar to the `aes()` call, so that you get a separate raincloud plot for every 10 Times. The `%/%` operator is "integer division," which provides the closest integer from the division step. It's useful here as a way of grouping a range of Time values together. You might alternatively use something like `group = floor(Time / 10)` for a similar effect.

[image]

Showing all 1000 Times separately (e.g. with `group = Time`) seems like it will be hard to discern:

[image]

EDIT: Here's the relevant code line for 25 rainclouds, 40 time steps each:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Time, y = profits, fill = ID, group = Time %/% 40)) +
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)
source("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/benmarwick/2a1bb0133ff568cbe28d/raw/fb53bd97121f7f9ce947837ef1a4c65a73bffb3f/geom_flat_violin.R")
raincloud_theme <- theme(
  text = element_text(size = 10),
  axis.title.x = element_text(size = 16),
  axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16),
  axis.text = element_text(size = 14),
  axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5),
  legend.title = element_text(size = 16),
  legend.text = element_text(size = 16),
  legend.position = "right",
  plot.title = element_text(lineheight = .8, face = "bold", size = 16),
  panel.border = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
  axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"),
  axis.line.y = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"))

set.seed(123)
ID = rep(c("BAU","IMP","SGR","CR"), each=5000)
Time = rep (c(1:1000), each = 20)
data <- data.frame( ID, Time,  profits = runif(20000,0,1))

data %>%
  mutate(TIME = ((Time - 1) %/% 40) + 1,
         TIME = factor(TIME)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = TIME, y = profits, fill = ID)) +
  geom_flat_violin(aes(fill = ID),
                   position = position_nudge(x =.1, 
                                             y = 0), 
                   adjust = 1.5, trim = FALSE, alpha = .5, colour = NA) +
  geom_point(aes(x = as.numeric(ID)-.15, y =profits),
             position = position_jitter(width = .05), size = 1, shape = 20) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x =TIME,  y = profits, fill = ID),outlier.shape
               = NA, alpha = .5, width = .1, colour = "black") + 
  coord_flip() +
  scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Dark2")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2")+  theme_classic() + theme(legend.position="top") +
  ggtitle("Profits Across Pysical Experiments") +
    raincloud_theme
#> Warning in FUN(X[[i]], ...): NAs introduced by coercion
#> Warning in min(x): no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
#> Warning in max(x): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
#> Warning: Removed 20000 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi Anil, I have followed these codes for my data which contains 270000 rows I have grouped data and it is reduced to 27000 rows. It gives a very untidy and unexplainable graph. I have edited the initial post and uploaded it. How the plot you have mentioned can be improved for a larger data set? Thanks